# QuickBooks Desktop QBFC16. Cannot Create QBXMLRP2 COM Component

Tags: quickbooks, qbfc

Cannot Create QBXMLRP2 COM Component
I installed QBFC Version 16.0 64bits and I compiled a library hat was previously compiled in QBFC15.0 32bits (and it worked correctly when I call from a simple program) .

But when Installed QBFC16 64bits and recompile both the library an the program I recieved this errror :

*Cannot Create QBXMLRP2 COM Component*

Debugging the library it showed that the error appearead when the library is trying to open a connection with a company file that is already opened in QuickBooks.

That doesn't happen with QBFC Version 15.0 32bits.

Also I tried SDKTest and it also failed with this error:

*Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {45F5708E-3B43-4FA8-BE7E-A5F1849214CB} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).*

I uninstalled QBFC15.0 32bits and QBFC16.0 64bits and reinstalled QBFC16.0 64bits but the problem persist.

It looks like the QBXMLRP2.dll is not correctly registered, but unisntalling and reisntallingthe SDK didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I realized thta the problme was thta the version of QuickBooks I was using (2012) is 32bit. I tried with QuickBooks ES 2023 and It worked ok.

Comment: I'm facing this same issue but I'm using QBE 2023 and QBDFC16. I uninstalled the SDK already to no avail. What's odd is my integration tests work fine, but once I try to run the actual built application, I get this error when trying to create a Vendor in QBD.